# How to gather user input during a phone call on twilio

Tags: c#, ivr

```
string ACCOUNT_SID = "MytwilioSid";
string AUTH_TOKEN = "Twilio_Auth";
string actionUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/IVR";

TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);      
var options = new CallOptions();
options.Url = Uri.EscapeUriString("https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH24ecc440f79cXXXX?action=" + actionUrl);
options.To = "+9199XXXXXX8";
options.From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioPhone"].ToString();
var call = client.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
```

I'm using above code to make an IVR call, Call is going to the specified number but it is not redirecting to the mentioned actionurl when user clicks keys(numbers).